# How to request recent videos from multiple YouTube channels in one API call?

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have looked through the YouTube API documentation, but as far as I can tell there is no way to request information (such as a list of recently uploaded videos) from multiple YouTube channels efficiently.

From my understanding the first thing one needs to do is get the playlist ID for the "uploads" playlist per YouTube channel.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=OneDirectionVEVO&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

And then get the uploaded videos by using the playlist ID previously retrieved.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUbW18JZRgko_mOGm5er8Yzg&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

That's two requests per channel, which would be fine if it was just one or two channels, but not for hundreds of channels.

How can I efficiently group all these requests into one API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request multiple YouTube channels in one API call by using `Batch Processing` [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) supports batch processing, enablign you to execute up to 50 operations with a `single API request` rather than submit a separate request for each individual operation. A batch processing request can combine multiple query `(GET)`, insert `(POST)`, update `(PUT)` and delete `(DELETE)` operations. Each operation is contained within an  tag in the request.

To submit a batch processing request, you send a `POST` request to a batch URL. Each feed has its own batch URL, and when you submit a request to that `URL`, you can execute API operations on any entry in that feed. The batch URL for a feed appears in a `<link>` tag with a rel attribute value of `http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch`. The  tag is a subtag of the  tag for that feed.

```
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' ...>
<id>https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/USER_ID/playlists</id>
...
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch'
type='application/atom+xml'
href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USER_ID/playlists/batch?v=2'/>
```